# Icons on taskbar Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: icons, workspaces

[Look at the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNDq2.png)

So whenever I open an application and go into a different workspace it's still there and thats a problem and if you click on it, it redirects you to the workspace that is in it. Basically if Google chrome is in workspace 2 and I am in workspace 1 I can click the google chrome icon and it will take me to workspace 2. How do I disable that or can I just make certain applications only appear on the taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

> thats a problem

Not necessarily. For you, perhaps, but it is designed to work that way.

In Ubuntu 22.04, the current LTS version, a setting to change that behavior is exposed in "Settings", "Multitasking" (look under "Application switching").

In older Ubuntu versions, i.e. your LTS version 20.04, you can use dconf-editor or change the relevant settings using two terminal commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only false
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-workspaces false
```

Comment: so If the application is in workspace 2 and I go to workspace 2 this command will stop it? And what is settings do I have to install something?

Comment: uh I copied and pasted the text and it tells me                                                                           ben@john-HP-Laptop-17-by2xxx:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only-false

Comment: Usage:
  gsettings [--schemadir SCHEMADIR] set SCHEMA[:PATH] KEY VALUE

Set the value of KEY to VALUE

Arguments:
  SCHEMADIR A directory to search for additional schemas
  SCHEMA    The name of the schema
  PATH      The path, for relocatable schemas
  KEY       The key within the schema
  VALUE     The value to set